# Angular Routing with ngRoute doesn't work for some routes

Tags: angularjs, node.js, routes, ngroute

In my single page application I have used ngRoute for angular routing. But I am facing some problems for angular routing.

configuration :

```
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $routeProvider
        .when('/product',{
            templateUrl : 'views/product/template/product.html',
            controller  : 'productCtrl'
        })
        .when('/product/add',{
            templateUrl : 'views/product/template/add-product.html',
            controller  : 'productCtrl'
        })
});
```

When my routing path is /product then everything is ok. But when my routing path is /product/add then it seems an error. But if "/product/add"
 replace with just "/add" then that route is also ok. So I cant recognize whats the main problem on routing "/product/add".

Error :

```
http://localhost:3000/product/views/product/template/add-product.html 404 (Not Found)
```

here I have seen a problem. other route seems like :

```
http://localhost:3000/views/product/template/product.html
```

But error route has /product after server link.

Need some clarification & solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

configure the route properly with error pages. You can follow this fiddle example.

## HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/product">product</a></li>
    <li><a href="/product/add">add</a></li>
    <li><a href="/other">Other</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
</div>
```

## Angular

```
var app = angular.module( "myApp", [] );

app.config( function ( $routeProvider,$locationProvider ) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
  $routeProvider
    .when( '/product', { template: 'I am product root' } )
    .when( '/product/add', { template: 'Adding a product' } )
    .when( '/other', { template: 'Other pages' } )
    .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/product' } );
});

app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function ( $scope ) {
});
```

for more https://jsfiddle.net/zahiruldu/jLdce3vj/186/

You can use UI Router for handling parent routing properly that will give you advance nested route facilities.